# Why does webpack create extra files when I place entries in folders?

Tags: webpack

If I specify a folder structure for my files like below:

```
entry: {
        "lib/polyfill": ["./src/lib/polyfill.ts"],
        "lib/vendor-angular": ["./src/lib/vendor-angular.ts"],
        "lib/vendor-rxjs": ["./src/lib/vendor-rxjs.ts"],
        "app/app": ["./src/main.ts"]
    },
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js",
        publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/"
    },
```

The folder structure that gets created is strange, with small files in both locations... in the root and where I specified. Haven't yet been able to find anything about this.

```
wwwroot
|--app
|  |--
|  |  |--app.js
|--lib
|  |--
|  |  |--polyfill.js
|  |  |--vendor-angular.js
|  |  |--vendor-rxjs.js
|--app.js
|--polyfill.js
|--vendor-angular.js
|--vendor-rxjs.js
```

I want to keep that root path clean. How do I do that?

`webpackJsonp([4,5,6,7],[]);` is an example of what is in some of these files in the `wwwroot`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to specify a folder in which you want [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) to put its generated files, is specifying it in the "path" entry in the "output".

You made [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) put the generated files in "wwwroot" directory, instead of "lib", but you also gave the entries names with directories, which caused [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) put the generated files in this directories as well.

You should change the entries to be just names, without any relative path, and define the directory you want for the generated files in the "path" entry.